# Kruskal's Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, performance, graph-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I am looking for C++ Kruskal implementations to benchmark against my own...
If you know a few good ones, please share!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's [`boost::kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/graph/doc/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.html). Prim's algorithm is there too if you want to compare against that.

Comment: @toto: What's evil about templates? Besides, the templates in this case do nothing but allow the algorithm to work with both graph matricies and adjacency lists.

Comment: I have a lot of things against templates. They add a lot of complexity to a language that is already difficult. I can do everything I want in C and C++ but when it's template code i don't understand a thing. They add bloat, compile times, nice error messages and they are not easy to debug.

Comment: I only really use the STL. It saves me some time when I program but it was harder to learn than the C library.

Comment: @toto: They add complexity because they do something \*useful\*. Most things that are useful do.